# unable to submit form (html, php)

Tags: php, html, forms

This site is amazing but I've finally found myself in over my head.
I'm writing a basic form to be submitted to a php script that emails the results to me.
The submit button simple does nothing. Can anyone help me figure out what the problem is?

Live version can be seen here: http://adamgalushacsis310.com/contact.html

here is my code:

```css
/* links */
a:link {color: inherit; text-decoration: none;}

a:visited {color: inherit; text-decoration: none;}

a:hover {text-decoration: underline; font-weight: bold; color: inherit;}

a:active {text-decoration: none; style: none;}

/* body formatting */
body {
 background-color: white;
 color: black;
 }
 
 
 /*css styling for individual divs*/
.li  {
 display: list-item; 
 margin-left: 2em
 }
 
.floatingbanner {
 float:right; 
 padding-right:10px;
 padding-top:10px;
}
.floatingidtag {
 float:right; 
 padding-right:10px;
 padding-top:10px;
}

#contactformcontainer{
 text-align: center;
}
#contactform{
 margin:auto;
 width: 100%;
 }

#cfleft{
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: left; 
 }

#cfright{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
 }

 
#header {
 margin:0px auto;
 width: 300px;
 }

#menu {
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
 width: 100%;
 padding-left: 12.5%
 }

#content{
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
 width: 75%;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 10px;
 overflow:auto;
 }

#aboutmeheaderplaceholder{
 /* stil debating on using this or no*/
 height: 250px;
}

#footer {
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
 width: 100%;
 clear:both;
 }
```

```html
<!-- begin contact form -->
   <form action="http://adamgalushacsis310.com/form_send.php" method="post">
   <div id="contactformcontainer">
    <div id="contactform">
    
     
      <div id="cfleft">
       First Name:<BR>
       <input name="first_name" type="text" size="12"><BR>
      </div>
      <div id="cfright">    
       Last Name:<BR>
       <input name="last_name" type="text" size="20"><BR>
      </div>
    </div>
    <BR>
    <div id="contactform">
     <div id="cfleft">
      Email Address:<BR>
      <input name="email" type="text" size="37"><BR>
     </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="contactform">
     <div id="cfleft">
      Address:<BR>
      <input name="address" type="text" size="37"><BR>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contactform">
     <div id="cfleft">
      City:<br>
      <input name="city"type="text">
     </div>
     <div id="cfright">
      State:<BR>
      <select name="state" style="width:115px;">
       <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
       <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
       <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
       <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
       <option value="CA">California</option>
       <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
       <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
       <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
       <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
       <option value="FL">Florida</option>
       <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
       <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
       <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
       <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
       <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
       <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
       <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
       <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
       <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
       <option value="ME">Maine</option>
       <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
       <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
       <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
       <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
       <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
       <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
       <option value="MT">Montana</option>
       <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
       <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
       <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
       <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
       <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
       <option value="NY">New York</option>
       <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
       <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
       <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
       <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
       <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
       <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
       <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
       <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
       <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
       <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
       <option value="TX">Texas</option>
       <option value="UT">Utah</option>
       <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
       <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
       <option value="WA">Washington</option>
       <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
       <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
       <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
      </select><BR>
     </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="contactform">
     <div id="cfleft">
      Phone Number: <BR>
      <input name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="xxx-xxx-xxxx"><BR>
     </div>
     <div id="cfright">
      Availability:<BR>
      <select name="availability>
       <option value="Morning">Morning</option>
       <option value="Afternoon">Afternoon</option>
       <option value="Evening">Evening</option>
      </select><BR>
     </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="contactform">
     <div id="cfleft">
      I am interested in contact for the following reason(s):<BR>
      <input type="checkbox" name="reason1" value="employment_interest">Employment Interest
      <input type="checkbox" name="reason2" value="consultation">Consultation
      <input type="checkbox" name="reason3" value="">Other<BR>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contactform">
     <div id="cfleft">
      <BR><textarea name="reason_other" rows="4" cols="40" placeholder="If Other, please explain."></textarea>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contactform">
     <div id="cfleft">
      <BR><input type="submit" value="Submit">
     </div>
     <div id="cfright">
      <input type="reset" value="Clear Fields">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   </form>
```

with the php file as follows:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
    $email_to = "numb1zero@gmail.com";

    $email_subject = "AdamGalushaCSIS310.com Contact Form Data";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email']) ||

        !isset($_POST['phone']) ||

        !isset($_POST['availability'])) {

        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $address = $_POST['address']; // not required
    $city = $_POST['city']; // not required
    $state = $_POST['state']; // not required
    $phone = $_POST['phone']; // required
    $availability = $_POST['availability']; // required
    $reason1 = $_POST['reason1']; // not required
    $reason2 = $_POST['reason2']; // not required
    $reason3 = $_POST['reason2']; // not required
    $reason_other = $_POST['reason_other']; // not required


    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($availability) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Availability you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Phone Number: ".clean_string($phone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Address: ".clean_string($address)."\n";
    $email_message .= "City: ".clean_string($city)."\n";
    $email_message .= "State: ".clean_string($state)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Best time to contact: ".clean_string($availability)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Contacting for: ".clean_string($reason1)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Contacting for: ".clean_string($reason2)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Contacting for: ".clean_string($reason3)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Contacting for: ".clean_string($reason_other)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- place your own success html below -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
die();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple error.

This:

```
<img src="images/contact.png" width="20%>
```

Should be

This:

```
<img src="images/contact.png" width="20%">
```

Comment: Oh wow...  I can't believe that's all it was.  You're a lifesaver! That you so much!!

Comment: But...  Now I get error 403 from the server on submit... A permissions error?

Comment: It´s is problem with your http server configuration.